# WS_EX_TRANSPARENT and stylus events

Tags: c++, winapi, window

I'm setting WS_EX_TRANSPARENT flag in window with the following code:

```
SetWindowLong( hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE,WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_COMPOSITED | WS_EX_LAYERED );
```

This flag make that mouse events go to windows system instead of my app.
When I set this, I can't get Stylus events in hwnd window. Any way to solve that or that's not possible?

Comment: WM_TOUCH???  That's not a style flag.  Enabling touch requires calling RegisterTouchWindow().

Comment: Ok. Same behavior without this. Question edited.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior for the `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` extended window style for [Layered Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#layered) is documented:

> [I]f the layered window has the **WS_EX_TRANSPARENT** extended window style, the shape of the layered window will be ignored and the mouse events will be passed to other windows underneath the layered window.

*Note: The rules for input handling are usually the same, for all pointing devices. Whenever you read* "mouse events" *you can expand that to* "input events from a pointing device"*.*

One workaround is given in the documentation for [WS_EX_TRANSPARENT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543.aspx):

> To achieve transparency without these restrictions, use the [**SetWindowRgn**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145102.aspx) function.

Comment: I need whole window of my application, not only a region of that. Also, I need the mouse events pass to other windows and only get stylus events.

Comment: About your edit: I can get mouse events in WS_EX_TRANSPARENT window using MouseHook but not Stylus events.

Comment: @juangrdiazrestu: As I pointed out in my answer, input from all pointing devices is handled the same. If you wish to have different behavior, you will have to implement the filtering yourself. I'm also somewhat convinced, that you are using `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` for something it wasn't meant for. Make sure to read [Like the cake, WS_EX_TRANSPARENT is a lie, or at least not the entire truth](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/12/17/10378525.aspx).

Comment: I can't filter events that I can't get so that's is not a solution. About the second, I think I have very clear a concept of WS_EX_TRANSPARENT in winapi.

Comment: You specifically asked that the mouse events were to be passed to the window underneath. The system did what you told it to do.

Comment: @juangrdiazrestu: No offense, but someone passing `WM_TOUCH` for an extended window **style** is likely not the same person that has the basics straight. I'd recommend you read the link I posted.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, that is clear. My question now is how I can get stylus events not the mouse events. The mouse events were passed to the window underneath but I can get using MouseHook. Any similar to get stylus events?

Comment: So it's a new question? Post it as such. This ain't no chatroom honey!

Comment: new question? Every time is the same question, get Stylus event in WS_EX_TRANSPARENT window.

Comment: @juangrdiazrestu: If you need to monitor touch input for a window that doesn't accept input from a pointing device, you can use the [Raw Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx) API. This is very tedious. There will be no equivalent to `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK`, `WM_MOUSEHOVER`, `WM_MOUSELEAVE`, and so on. And there will be no distinction as to whether the pointing device is over the client or non-client area of a window. Lots of manual work, and lots of ways to fail.